# My select_first function doesn't choose the very first element

Tags: r, lapply

I'm a beginner with R. 
I tried making a function that **selects the first element of a vector**.
Then I used the function with lapply on my vector. 
However, **instead of choosing the first set of student and score, all students pop out..**
I understand my function is selecting the first element per group(?) of the vector. But can anyone explain **why** my function results in the students instead of the first student and score?

Help please. Thanks!

```
student_score <- c("Philip:70", "Jimmy:80", "Alex:90", "Steve:100")

split_score <- strsplit(student_score, split = ":")

select_first <- function(x) {
    x[1]
}

unlist(lapply(split_score, select_first)) 
#Used unlist() just to make the view of the result simpler
```

Expected Result: "Philip" "70" /// Actual Result: "Philip" "Jimmy" "Alex" "Steve"

Comment: do you need `split_score[[1]]` ?

Comment: No I'm wondering why this happens

Comment: `lapply` applies `select_first` to each element of `split_score`. This means it takes  each element, runs `select_first` and returns the results as a list. If you run `select_first(split_score))` you'll get a list version of what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

the `lapply` function is just hiding a `for` loop around each element of `split_score`. Here what's inside of it after the `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(student_score, split = ":") # gives a list
[[1]]
[1] "Philip" "70"    

[[2]]
[1] "Jimmy" "80"   

[[3]]
[1] "Alex" "90"  

[[4]]
[1] "Steve" "100"
```

So your call to `lapply` could be translated like this:

- for each element in `split_score` (each element is the pair name-score)
- extract the first (`x[1]`)

So at the first iteration of the loop inside `lapply` the `x` is `x = c("Philip" "70")` and `x[1]` is `"Philip"`, and so on.

That's why you get the list of names. Note that `lapply` is just hiding the `for` loop.

Your `lapply` is basically doing this:

```
for (i in 1:4){
     split_score[[i]][1] 
    }
```

Comment: Ah~ understood! Thank you very much!!